# Django Celery - running scheduled tasks

Tags: celery, django-celery

After several hours on this without results I really need an help.

I configured Django-Celery on my Django App and I'm able to run scheduled tasks with:

```
python manage.py celeryd -E -B -l INFO
```

Now it's time for production and it's here that my pain begins.
I configured `celeryd` as daemon. It's seems working, but scheduled tasks won't run.

So I added `-B` in the `CELERYD_OPTS`.
My tasks now run as scheduled but I have this boring lines on my log:

```
[2014-02-17 22:37:30,738: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
```

I just want to remove that lines from my log! I don't even understand what that it means.

So I configured the `celerybeat` daemon, thinking that this would be the cleaner and suggest solution for a production environment.

Unfortunately when I stat the `celerybeat` daemon it creates a log and a pid file but scheduled tasks do not run.

```
[2014-02-17 19:15:41,919: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2014-02-17 19:15:41,921: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2014-02-17 19:15:42,072: DEBUG/MainProcess] Current schedule:
<ModelEntry: celery.backend_cleanup celery.backend_cleanup(*[], **{}) {4}>
<ModelEntry: MyApp.tasks.test_task MyApp.tasks.test_task(*[], **{}) {4}>
[2014-02-17 19:15:42,187: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Ticking with max interval->5.00 seconds
[2014-02-17 19:15:42,206: DEBUG/MainProcess] Start from server, version: 0.9, properties: {u'information': u'Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/', u'product': u'RabbitMQ', u'copyright': u'Copyright (C) 2007-2011 VMware, Inc.', u'capabilities': {u'exchange_exchange_bindings': True, u'consumer_cancel_notify': True, u'publisher_confirms': True, u'basic.nack': True}, u'platform': u'Erlang/OTP', u'version': u'2.7.1'}, mechanisms: [u'PLAIN', u'AMQPLAIN'], locales: [u'en_US']
[2014-02-17 19:15:42,207: DEBUG/MainProcess] Open OK!
[2014-02-17 19:15:42,257: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task MyApp.tasks.test_task (MyApp.tasks.test_task)
```

And nothing more.

Everything in my understanding works fine (RabbitMQ included, whose log is clean and without errors)

I just need to avoid long useless lines on my log file.
Clean and quick solution.

Anyone can help? 
Thanks!!

Comment: The DEBUG log should note be included when you use `loglevel=INFO`, so I guess something else must be setting the loglevel.  I remember Django used to do that, but I'm not quite sure how to fix it.  Not sure what you mean by 'tasks do not run', the log from your beat process explicitly states that a task was sent.  Do you mean that the task is not executed by a worker? Did you start a worker with the beat instance?

Comment: It seems there was a collision with Django-debug-toolbar I ended up removing the app from Django settings in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue disabling django-debug-toolbar in the production environment. 
https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1877

It seems that django-celery and django-debug-toolbar sometimes may mess the logging configuration.